# Storing references in object yielding wierd results

Tags: c++

A bit of context: I was testing the compiler's optimizations when using references (they are very good at it BTW).
At some point I passed two objects by reference to a struct constructor... and things got wierd. I can see changes made to one of the objects outside the struct, but not the other.

I came with a minimal working example of what I mean by that:

```
//TwoInts has two references to int
//For whatever reason I can only see outside changes
//done to the int pointed by ref1 !
struct TwoInts{
    int& ref1,ref2;
    TwoInts(int& r1,int& r2):ref1(r1),ref2(r2){}
};

int foo(int select){
    int a=0,b=0;
    TwoInts two(a,b);

    switch(select){
        case 1:
            a=1; //This line changes the output
            return two.ref1; //Returns 1, ok
            break;
        case 2:
            b=2; //This line DOESN'T change the output
            return two.ref2; //Returns zero!
            break;
    }
}
```

Generated assembler with g++ v5.4 using -O2

```
foo(int):
  cmp edi, 1
  je .L3
  cmp edi, 2
  jne .L9
  xor eax, eax
  ret
.L9:
  rep ret
.L3:
  mov eax, 1
  ret
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'//TwoInts+has+two+references+to+int%0A//For+whatever+reason+I+can+only+see+outside+changes%0A//done+to+the+int+pointed+by+ref1+!!%0Astruct+TwoInts%7B%0A++++int%26+ref1,ref2%3B%0A++++TwoInts(int%26+r1,int%26+r2):ref1(r1),ref2(r2)%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+foo(char+select)%7B%0A++++int+a%3D0,b%3D0%3B%0A++++TwoInts+two(a,b)%3B%0A%0A++++switch(select)%7B%0A++++++++case+!'1!':%0A++++++++++++a%3D1%3B+//This+line+changes+the+output%0A++++++++++++return+two.ref1%3B+//Returns+1,+ok%0A++++++++++++break%3B%0A++++++++case+!'2!':%0A++++++++++++b%3D2%3B+//This+line+DOESN!'T+change+the+output%0A++++++++++++return+two.ref2%3B+//Returns+zero!!%0A++++++++++++break%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g540,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321059175482589025111:(display:'')),length:1)),trim:'0'),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

-If I pass 1 to foo the code jumps to .L3 and returns 1, reflecting the change made to a;

-But if I pass 2 to foo the code jumps to .L9 and returns 0, **ignoring** the change made to b.

I have no clue why this is happening. Any thoughts on that?

[EDIT]
It is really easy to run in circles when you are working alone. Indeed, the type of ref2 is just int, not int&. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: It is better to keep one declaration per line as mistakes like this are easy.

Comment: In `int& ref1, ref2` `ref2` is not a reference. The `&` applies to `ref1`, not to `int`.

Comment: Ouch, I really missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have declared `ref1` and `ref2` makes `ref1` an `int` reference but `ref2` an `int` value.

The correct declaration to have two references in your struct should be:

```
int &ref1, &ref2;
```